How can I hide test path execution in pytest VScode
I'd like to hide PYTHON-EXEC-OUTPUT, is it possible? I don't find ways
in my search to do this.
>>>PYTHON-EXEC-OUTPUT
Received JSON data in run script
Error: No test ids received from stdin, could be an error or a run request without ids provided.
Running pytest with no test ids as args. Args being used:  ['--rootdir=c:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\EstudoFerramentaTeste']


My wish is to execute tests showing only information starting from "test session starts" (summary)

Have you tired to use the -q or --quiet flag which will reduce the verbosity of the test output?
